# flutter ListView KeepAlive after some scroll

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I want to `keepAlive` my widgets which are already rendered in `ListView`. I was tried with `addAutomaticKeepAlives:true` properties which provide by `ListView` class.

Here is my sample code which I was used. Same issue in `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` delegate which provide by `SliverList`.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
      return Card(
        child: Container(
          child: Image.asset("images/${index+1}.jpg",fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          height: 250.0,
        ),
      );
    },
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
    itemCount:40 ,
);
```

Answer (score 53):

For `automaticKeepAlive` to work, each item that needs to be kept alive must send a specific notification.

A typical way to fire such notification is using [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FooState createState() {
    return new FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Is this working for image ? i tried but images still re-render when i am scrolling. If scroll slowly that time there is no issue. but In fast scrolling image widget re-render.

Comment: Hi can you help at all? I'm facing a similar issue with CustomScrollView and SliverList... I have a WebView that keeps reloading when the page scrolls...

I have cacheExtent high enough on my CustomScrollView. I also have all the prerequisites such as: ```super.build(context);``` and the ```bool get  wantKeepAlive``` override... I also have the ```AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin``` set... Not sure what's going on, but the WebView definitely doesn't reload in something like a SingleChildScrollView.. SO I'm guessing it's the CustomScrollView/SliverList that's destroying it..

Comment: thanks for this, even having read: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html I didn't realized that was mentioned in the last point!

Comment: This solution has worked for me. However, I just want to express the confusion why it can not be simpler: first I tried the `KeepAlive` class as a wrapper, it returned me errors about `ParentData` that I don't quite understand since I'm new to Flutter. Also why we can not just have this property on `ListView` to keep everything alive by default. With Flutter we're really wrapping classes around classes all day long.

Answer (score 26):

As stated by AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and Remi's answer,

> Subclasses must implement wantKeepAlive, and their build methods must
> call super.build (the return value will always return null, and should
> be ignored).

Therefore, change your build method to:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FooState createState() {
    return new FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: `super.build(context);` really solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: "The method 'build' is always abstract in the supertype"

Comment: ^ I get the same result. You can no longer call this method from State it seems...

Answer (score 10):

You can try looking at the cacheExtent property on listview builder as well. Setting that to a value to cover your items will keep them all alive. 
Thanks to Remi above. I had no idea the items needed keepAlive when using it on the list - that was not in the flutter doco previously...

Answer (score 6):

if you want to keep alive a list of slivers (for CustomScrollView) all you need to do is use the 'SliverChildListDelegate' instead of 'SliverChildBuilderDelegate'

Here's my code:

```
final List<Product> products;
return CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
    slivers: [
      _mySliverAppBar(context, title),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          List.generate(products.length, (index) => _myProductCard(context,products[index]))
        )
        // SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        //   (context, index) => _myProductCard(context, products[index]),
        //   childCount: products.length,
        // ),
      ),
   ],
);
```

As you can see in the code, I was using SliverChildBuilderDelegate before