# How to build a list of videos with flutter and firebase?

Tags: flutter, video, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter, I want to build a list of videos with flutter and firebase so, I built it with `ListView.builder()` it worked but as you know `ListView.builder()` only builds what is on the screen so, If I scrolled down and want to see something up, It will rebuild, I don't want it to rebuild.

> Code

```
return StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('Khatma Collection')
            .document('Khatma 1')
            .collection('Videos')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                var rng = new Random();
                int ii = rng.nextInt(4);
                if (ii == iii) {
                } else {
                  iii = ii;
                  var link = snapshot.data.documents[ii].data['Link'];
                  var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[ii].data['Uploader'];
                  var likes = snapshot.data.documents[ii].data['Likes'];
                  var like = likes.toString();
                  bool liked;
                  if (int.parse(like) > 0) {
                    liked = true;
                  } else if (int.parse(like) == 0) {
                    liked = false;
                  }
                  final videoPlayerController =
                      VideoPlayerController.network(link);
                  chewieController = ChewieController(
                    allowMuting: true,
                    autoInitialize: true,
                    deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: orientation,
                    allowFullScreen: true,
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                  );
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Chewie(
                          controller: chewieController,
                        ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Is addAutomaticKeepAlive a solution ? A property in ListView.builder()

Comment: I think you should specify your question since you only detail what `ListView().builder` does.

Comment: see my edit up .

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541172/flutter-listview-keepalive-after-some-scroll]