# Can I prevent the ExpansionTile from rebuilding its children?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an `ExpansionTile` widget and it contains some `children`, what I want is to prevent the `ExpansionTile` from **rebuilding** its children when I **expand** it.

**Is there any basic method or will I have to do some trick?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make this `maintainState` value `true` like this:

```
ExpansionTile(
    maintainState: true,
    children: [
    ...
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure try to use automaticKeepAlive it will keep your widget alive without building again

If you want to keep it without building as a constant , you can use const type

For automaticKeepAlive check :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html

Here more like  this q & a

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52543119/11989529

Comment: Unfortunately I tried to use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and it didn't work :(, It must not work with the ExpansionTile , Do you have any other solution, thank you

Comment: Farouk can you share with me the code with automaticKeep ..?